# How to change the variable from one .m file to another ,m file?

Tags: xcode4

In my program, I have declared a variable int a = 4 in view2.m file.
If I want to change the variable a to a = 6 in view1.m file so that the the variable a in view1.m is changed to a = 6 at the same time. How should I do ? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hardcoded numbers. Use a class constant or even use the preprocessor. But hardcoded numbers are almost always a bad practice.

Comment: Could you give a real example, the source code, to implement your ideal? Thank you deeply!

Comment: Put "#define MYVALUE 4" in views.h, include "views.h" in both files, set a to MYVALUE in both view1.m and view2.m. That's using the preprocessor. See [link]http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#in-class[/lin] for a way to do it if you are using classes.

Comment: I have tried it... however, this method can only help me to recall the constant value MYVALUE, i cannot change the value a at different views. Or do I misunderstand your approach ?

Comment: as long as both .m files #include the same .h file with the constant it, when you change the constant then both .m files will have the new value. Try putting some example code showing the problem in your question.